# If $f$ is absolutely continuous and $g$ is continuous, prove $f' =g$.

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

The full problem reads:

Prove that if $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ and $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $f'=g$ a.e., then $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and $f'=g$.

My analysis skills are very rusty and I'm having a hard time seeing how to prove this. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Lebesgue's fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity),
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'. $$
By hypothesis,
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x g.$$
By the standard fundamental theorem of calculus, $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: That's correct, but you should fill in a few details to make it useful for the OP and other users.

Comment: @ProfessorVector What details?

Comment: The link Aloizio attaches gives any details needed I believe

Comment: I think the proof is OK without any further details needed. Since $g$ is continuous its Lebesgue integral can be treated as a Riemann integral and then $f'=g$ everywhere in $[0, 1] $.